# Convert string name into variable in php?

Tags: php, arrays, function, variables, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a function in php that will convert 3 strings into an element in a multidimensional array.  So the array at the moment is this:

```
`$testcart=[$testcamera = [
'name' => 'Sony camera',
'price' => 170
   ]
    ];

$phone = [
    'name' => 'Lg g3',
    'price' => 400

];'
```

And I'm trying to add this element to it through a form:

```
    `$smartphone = [
    'name' => 'HTC One',
    'price' => 300

];`
```

So the user inputs 'smartphone,'htc one', and 300.  I've created this function:

```
function newcreate_item($newitemvariable,$newitemname,$newitemprice) {
    $newitem = "$" . $newitemvariable;
    $newitem = [
    'name' =>$newitemname,
    'price' =>$newitemprice];
     return $newitem; 
}
```

But I cannot seem to convert the string ($newitemvariable) into the variable name. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: first of all, don't do it... there are too many things that can go wrong with this ... way too many.. If you do insist on doing that, use extract function http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Answer (score 0):

Except it is quite risky and not professional to do so the right function to use is eval():

```
php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > $str = '$testcart=[
php ' [
php ' \'name\' => \'Sony camera\',
php ' \'price\' => 170
php ' ],
php ' [
php '     \'name\' => \'Lg g3\',
php '     \'price\' => 400
php ' 
php ' ]];';
php > eval($str);
php > var_dump($testcart);
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "Sony camera"
    ["price"]=>
    int(170)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Lg g3"
    ["price"]=>
    int(400)
  }
}
php >
```